# Lambda expression Evaluation

Tags: lambda-calculus

```
( (λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y ^2 ) ) (5)
```

I tried finding out the order of evaluation for this lambda expression. How is this lambda expression evaluated?

Comment: This question is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

λ-calculus doesn't define an "order of evaluation". Investigating the behavior of different orders of evaluation is one of the issues that the λ-calculus sheds light on.

For example, one can use the "applicative order" strategy used by most conventional programming languages, which is that to evaluate $(\lambda x.A) B$ one first evaluates $B$ to its normal form, and then inserts this normal form into $A$ in place of $x$. But if $B$ has no normal form, this procedure might not terminate, even if $\lambda x.A$ never looks at its argument because $x$ does not appear in $A$.  One can use instead the "normal order" strategy, where one substitutes $B$ into $A$ immediately, without evaluating it.  A theorem of Church and Rosser says that this is guaranteed to reduce the entire expression to a normal form, if it has one.

For your example, $( (λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y ^2 ) ) (5)$, one can proceed by applicative order:

$$\begin{array}{c}
( (λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y ^2 ) ) (5) \\
(λx.(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 )(x))) (5) \\
(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 ) 5)  \\
(λy.y ^2 )(5 ^2 )  \\
(5 ^2 ) ^2   \\
\end{array}
$$

Normal order begins the same, but proceeds differently once it reaches the $(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 ) 5)$ step:
$$\begin{array}{c}
( (λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y ^2 ) ) (5) \\
(λx.(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 )(x))) (5) \\
(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 ) 5)  \\
((λy.y ^2 ) 5) ^2   \\
(5 ^2 )  ^2   \\
\end{array}
$$

The end result is the same, as the Church-Rosser theorem says it must be.

Comment: Why does $\lambda y.y^{2}$ get replaced by $x$ though?

Comment: It doesn't get replaced by $x$.

Comment: How does one get from $( (λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y ^2 ) ) (5)$ to
$(λx.(λy.y ^2 )((λy.y ^2 )(x))) (5)$?

Comment: Evaluate the leftmost redex, substituting $\lambda y.y^2$ for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation in lambda calculus can't be decided uniquely.

`(λx. (λy. y^2) ((λy. y^2) x)) 5` can be evaluated to

`(λy. y^2) ((λy. y^2) 5)` or `(λx. ((λy. y^2) x)^2) 5` or `(λx. (λy. y^2) x^2) 5`.